# Unique Permissions for a group

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions

I have a library with unique permissions on specific documents which were created by sharing those documents.

I have a SP group which I want to grant it a unique permission to each one of these documents.

I'm looking for a PowerShell solution as I can't grant permission to each one by its own as it will take a lot of time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can save the relevant document ID as a CSV file and use PnP PowerShell command to set item permission for these documents:

[image]

```
$SiteURL = "https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename"
$ListName ="LibraryName"
$GroupName="SPGroupName"
Connect-PnPOnline -URL $SiteURL
Import-Csv -Path C:\itemid.csv | ForEach-Object {  
  $ListItemID = $_.ListItemID
  $Group = Get-PnPGroup | where-Object {$_.Title -eq $GroupName}
  Set-PnPListItemPermission -Identity $ListItemID -List $ListName -AddRole "Full Control" -Group $Group
}
```